# moving file from directory to another and renaming file

Tags: python, directory, rename, move

CHANGE OF HEART!
I just found an easy way to work out the moving the file by using an alias. So now I simply want to add a .jpg extensions. The file so far are called something like this: "00A31A2B77FC148DC8718F6C2E9C8D09" so no extension! 
So how can I add the extention .jpg of all the files in a specific folder, and if the file cannot be converted (cause this can happen) skip this file and go on to the next.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I wrote a piece of code which moves a files and renames them. However it seems like there are two issues:
 1. an issue with the renaming (.j.jpg) (and it keeps renaming the files with every time I run the script
2. it works only with one specific file, as soon as I place another file in the folder it does not work anymore

```
import glob, os, shutil
import glob, os


source_dir = "/path/to/Desktop/1"
dst = "/path/top/Desktop/2"
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.jpg"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.move(file, dst)

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join("/Users/shirin/Desktop/2", '*')):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.jpg')
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-2] + '.jpg')
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Could you provide example with your input data (list of files in `source_dir`) and desired output data?

Comment: renaming twice the same file `os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.jpg')
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-2] + '.jpg')` cannot work.

Comment: and you could move+rename at the same time.

Comment: Why do you use `rename` twice?

Comment: I changed my purpose!